# ncurses.h not outputting color change in c

Tags: c, for-loop, colors, ncurses

I am trying to have the text in my game fade away when my player selects "play". To do so, I thought of changing the color value of the text slowly into black. Below, I have selected a portion of my code that involves the changing color values. When you run the program, it won't output anything. I believe it has something to do with using variable 'i' inside of the init_color() function. Any help would be seriously appreciated

```
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define SLOW_ROLL usleep(200000)
#define BORDER_INSIDE_Y 40

int main()
{

  int i, row, col;
  initscr(); // Begin ncurses
  cbreak();
  keypad(stdscr, TRUE);
  curs_set(0);
  noecho();
  getmaxyx(stdscr, row, col);
  start_color();
  init_pair(1, COLOR_RED, COLOR_BLACK);
  for(i = 1000; i < 0; --i)
  {
    init_color(COLOR_RED, i, 0, 0);
    attron(COLOR_PAIR(1));
    mvprintw((row / 2) - (BORDER_INSIDE_Y / 2) + 10, (col / 2) - 11, "Welcome to The Game");
    attroff(COLOR_PAIR(1));
    SLOW_ROLL; // usleep function for about .2 seconds
    refresh();
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `for` loop will not run. `for(i = 1000; i < 0; --i)` makes no sense, you probably mean to use `>` instead of `<`.

Also, .2 seconds is wayyyy too slow for a `for` loop that will run 1000 times. At .2 seconds, it would take your loop 200 seconds to complete.

Comment: Ahhhh, there ya go. I tried something else and solved my issue, but that would explain why I wasn't getting an output. Thanks